# How to wait until all async/sync loops are completed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, foreach

I have created a small Chrome extensions which processes all the opened tabs and downloads only the tabs with single images in it. The code works fine.

But I also want to wait for all the loops and commands in my code to finish, so after that I can start tracking if any downloads have initiated and when they are completed.
The problem is that I dont know how to wait for the entire loop process with its internal sync/async loops to first complete before I start tracking the downloads with Chrome's api.

I understand that there are many duplicate topics like my own which provide some solutions. I have read them and tried to use some methods like async/wait and All.promises and replace tabs.forEach with tabs.map. But I cant make it work, the only progress I made is to wait until the entire forEach loop ends, but the problem remains with the chrome.tabs.executeScript async function, which still runs.

this is my original code without trying the solutions. it works as it is.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {//1
       tabs.forEach(tab => {//2
        console.log('Tab ID: ', tab.id);
        console.log('Tab URL: ', tab.url);
        console.log('Tab TITLE: ', tab.title);      
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'document.contentType'}, ([ mimeType ]) => {//3
        var mediav1=mimeType;                   
        for (var i = 0, iLen = mediaArray.length; i < iLen; i++) {//4
            if (mediav1.indexOf(mediaArray[i]) > -1) {                         
               chrome.downloads.download({
               url: tab.url, 
               conflictAction: 'uniquify', 
               saveAs: false
               },
               function(){      
               alert("Download")
               });
              }           
        }//4             
        });//3
    });//2
alert("Done")
 });//1
```

I have inserted two alerts, Done and Download.  The alert("Done") always appears first and then the alert("Download") second. I want for Done to appear after all the internal loops have finished and all downloads (if any) have been initiated.

Comment: I'd convert your async calls into `Promises` and leverage `Promise.all`

Comment: Example: [How to make Chrome Downloads API wait until a download has ended?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51601659)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your codes as follows:-

```
const execScript = (tab) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'document.contentType'}, ([ mimeType ]) => {//3
      var mediav1=mimeType;
      for (var i = 0, iLen = mediaArray.length; i < iLen; i++) {//4
        if (mediav1.indexOf(mediaArray[i]) > -1) {
          chrome.downloads.download({
              url: tab.url,
              conflictAction: 'uniquify',
              saveAs: false
            },
            () => {
              resolve("Done")
            });
        }
      }//4
    });//3  
  });
}

//then get all tabs and then create a function call
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, async (tabs) => {
  const promiseArray = tabs.map(tab => {
    return execScript(tab);
  })
  const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
  console.log(result);
  console.log("Done")
})
```